# Convert Full Date and Day

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering if it possible to convert a Full Date and Day e.g.

> Thursday 18th of April 2013

to a `string` (DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: If you want specific output from a specific entity/type, then show us the code and your desired result.

Comment: A programming language in which this problem is solvable in principle is called a _Convert-Full-Date-and-Day complete_ language. C# is designed to be Convert-Full-Date-and-Day complete.

Answer (score 5):

Yes check into [Standard Date Time Format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), and [Custom Date Time Format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way, but here is a quick method that came to mind based upon my understanding of your question.  There is a bit of extra code, so that you can add into a blank Windows form project and see the value.

```
String strEntry = @"Thursday 18th of April 2013";
DateTime dteValue = DateTime.MinValue;
strEntry = strEntry.Replace("of", null);
strEntry = strEntry.Replace("rd ", " ");
strEntry = strEntry.Replace("th", null);
strEntry = strEntry.Replace("st", null);
DateTime.TryParse(strEntry, out dteValue);
String strFormat = dteValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
MessageBox.Show(strFormat, "Date Value", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Comment: Wont strEntry.Replace("rd", null); replace the rd in Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `DateTime.Parse(string str)` method.

For example,
`DateTime.Parse("Thu, 18 April 2013");`

gives the following output,

`04/18/2013 00:00:00`